# Mock AutoMapper Mapper.Map call using Moq

Tags: c#, moq, automapper

Whats the best way to setup a mock expection for the Map function in AutoMapper.

I extract the IMapper interface so I can setup expects for that interface. My mapper has dependencies, so I have to pass those in to the mapper.

What happens when I create 2 instances of my mapper class, with 2 different dependency implementations? I asume that both mappers will use the same dependency instance, since the AutoMapper map is static. Or AutoMapper might even throw an exception because I try to setup 2 different maps with the same objects.?

Whats the best way to solve this?

```
public interface IMapper {
    TTarget Map<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source);
    void ValidateMappingConfiguration();
}

public class MyMapper : IMapper {
    private readonly IMyService service;

    public MyMapper(IMyService service) {
        this.service = service
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyModelClass, MyDTO>()
            .ForMember(d => d.RelatedData, o => o.MapFrom(s =>
                service.getData(s.id).RelatedData))
    }

    public void ValidateMappingConfiguration() {
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    public TTarget Map<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source) {
        return Mapper.Map<TSource, TTarget>(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 68):

You don't need to mock AutoMapper, you can just inject the real one as explained [here](https://kenbonny.net/injecting-automapper-profiles-in-tests):

```
var myProfile = new MyProfile();
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(myProfile));
IMapper mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
```

You can inject this mapper in your unit tests. The whole point of using tools like AutoMapper is for you not having to write a lot of mapping code. If you mock AutoMapper you'll end up having to do that.

Comment: I can still open it.

Comment: Weird. It seems my ISP is blocking the site then? `Error 522 Ray ID: 5798fed7d802d24c • 2020-03-25 13:32:00 UTC
Connection timed out` If you could somehow help me view it, by exporting it to maybe time machine, that'd be great.

Comment: Agreed. Mock mapper in each model is a waste of time, except you need to check if your mapper profile is correct.

Comment: If you understand best practices, this should be the accepted answer. You want to be mocking service/client responses, not mapping responses, let your mock flow thru the actual mapping logic then test the results.

Answer (score 51):

> Whats the best way to setup a mock expection for the Map function in AutoMapper[?]

Here's one way:

```
var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<Foo, Bar>(It.IsAny<Foo>())).Returns(new Bar());
```

Comment: Just a small addition.
`mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<Foo, Bar>(It.IsAny<Foo>())).Returns((Foo src) => new Bar(){ Value = src.Value});`

Comment: This solution works fine, but use below answer from @ataravati, which helps lot of time

Answer (score 3):

http://richarddingwall.name/2009/05/07/mocking-out-automapper-with-dependency-injection/

Points out another way of handling dependencies to AutoMapper, which basically will replace my attempt to extract my own IMapper interface. Instead I will attempt to use the existing IMappingEngine as dependency for my classes, to see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is setup AutoMapper like this (StructureMap is IoC). Then you can make your services dependent on IMappingEngine. From there mocking it should be very easy.

```
public class AutoMapperConfigurationRegistry : Registry
    {
        public AutoMapperConfigurationRegistry()
        {
            ForRequestedType<Configuration>()
                .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton)
                .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Configuration>()
                .CtorDependency<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>>().Is(expr => expr.ConstructedBy(MapperRegistry.AllMappers));

            ForRequestedType<ITypeMapFactory>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<TypeMapFactory>();

            ForRequestedType<IConfigurationProvider>()
                .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<Configuration>());

            ForRequestedType<IConfiguration>()
                .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<Configuration>());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to invoke automapper config is because, the UNIT Test cases instance runs outside of main application start up files/configs. Hence the auto mapper configuration has to be called and setup before any unit tests start to run. Ideally you place it in TestInitialize methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I provide an instance of AutoMapper as default Mock for IMapper, using AutoFixture and Moq:

*Thanks Lucian Bargaoanu for this hint: Actually you can use `cfg.AddMaps(params Assembly[])` and Automapper will search for profiles*

1. Create an `ICustomization`

```
public class MapperCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Register<IMapper>(() =>
        {
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddMaps(
                    Assembly.Load("BookSharing.Application"),
                    Assembly.Load("BookSharing.Infrastructure"));
            });

            return new Mapper(configuration);
        });
    }
}
```

2. Register the customization

```
fixture.Customize(new MapperCustomization());
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html?#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration

Comment: Thank you for that! I didn't know, honestly :) Apreciez bro

Answer (score 0):

following @Dorin Baba answer, I created a useful generic class that can be used to inject any custom mapper in the unit tests

```
public class MapperCustomization<T> : ICustomization
    where T : class
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Register<IMapper>(() =>
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddMaps(
                    typeof(T).Assembly);
            });

            return new Mapper(config);
        });
    }
}
```